# relying on Java's short-circuiting evaluation (coding style)

Tags: java, coding-style

Is it ever a good coding style to heavily rely on short-circuit in boolean evaluation?

I've known someone who loves to do this.
For instance, if the business logic is "If Alice is not hungry OR if both Alice and Bob are hungry", instead of writing

```
// if Alice is not hungry or both alice and bob are hungry
if (!A || A && B)`
```

he would write

```
// if Alice is not hungry OR both alice and bob are hungry
if (!A || B)
```

arguing that `||` is short-circuited, so the right-operand is evaluated if and only if the first one is `false` (which means `A = true`).

(The annoying thing about this is that at first glance, you would think this is a bug but then feel you would look stupid if you change it to what is more obvious!)

Comment: In boolean logic, it's probably ok. It's usually understandable by most programmers. It might be worth a comment though.

Comment: This is an opinion question, but in my experience I've seen Java short-circuiting used a lot to simplify boolean expressions. It's not too hard to read once you get used to it.

Comment: @AnubianNoob right, the problem is the dev would leave the comment that makes the predicate look more like a bug! (ie., the ocmment would state the business logic, while the predicate seems to be doing something else!)

Comment: In my opinion, it should only be used when you need to assert something before testing the next (testing if an object is null before calling a method from it). If a code "needs" a comment, its probably not that good.

Comment: Is the example about short-circuiting? Without short-circuiting, the semantic of "OR" alone makes the example work.

Comment: Compilers (or, in Java's case, Hotspot) are very good at common subexpression removal. Code should be readable by programmers, and should visibly conform to requirements.

Comment: You're relying on the Java order of operations in your first expression !A || A && B.  I would write it like this: (!A) || (A && B) to make it more readable to a human.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc (No thanks) (I (don't need) extra) help.

Answer (score 10):

You certainly can and should rely on short circuiting in expressions, but the example you give is just bad programming. The logic of the expression should match the comment and the human-readable logic of the test. The optimizer fully understands boolean logic and will optimize away any apparent inefficiency that your teammate might complain about.

The most important thing is to make the code clear and understandable for the developer. Writing clever code to prove how clever you are is never a good practice.

Answer (score 8):

Is it ever a good style?  Yes, I think most people can appreciate this idiomatic style:

```
myFoo != null && myFoo.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really have anything to do with short-circuiting; those two expressions would be equivalent even without short-circuiting:

```
A    B       !A | A & B     !A | B
-----------------------------------
0    0       1               1
0    1       1               1
1    0       0               0
1    1       1               1
```

Just pick whichever you think will be easier to understand and manage in the future; whichever more explicitly conveys your purpose. The clear winner in this regard seems to be your first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, whether it short circuits or not the results will be the same. He's not relying on short-circuiting here but rather in simplifying the logic that is required.

In my opinion there isn't a very solid black and white answer. I personally wouldn't simplify logic statements like this because for me it's hard to read when I would come back to it later. Adding the extra bit of logic to explicitly explain my checks wouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually "relying" on short circuit evaluation in this case. You are just simplifying a boolean expression. The logic works the same with both `&` and `&&`.

The effects of short-circuiting are:

- Avoid execution of the short-circuited code (which might have side-effects, throw an exception or fail to terminate)
- Potentially save some superfluous computation

Short-circuiting therefore doesn't change the boolean result in any way.